# SAS Macro Conditional Statement not Creating Table

Tags: sas, sas-macro

when I run the sas code below, it does not generate the table. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
%macro createData(test=);

%if 2+2 = 4 %then %do;

proc sql;
create table test as 

select

*

from datasets.mydata

;

quit;
%end;

%mend;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code runs fine as long as you actually call the macro!

You need one more line:

```
%createData(test=1);
```

(`test=1` is arbitrary, since you don't do anything with the `&test` macro parameter I just picked whatever I wanted).

SAS Macros are similar in other programming languages to methods - they don't do anything until they're called, running the macro definition itself just compiles the macro and gets it ready to be used.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work, the table was still not created

Comment: Ah, I understand, ok got it. Thanks!